# Qt installation error is "The tslib functionality test failed! "

Tags: linux, qt, embedded

I have ubuntu 14 and install arm-linuc-gcc 4.4.3 in this path : /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.4.3/bin.
and export the path and go step by step with this site:https://importgeek.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/compiling-qt-and-tslib-for-mini2440-and-run-a-demo-app/
(exactly use the command line in user owner not root ($) but for git command need to sudo keyword to install and for some other like Qt configure and Qt untar  used sudo keyword)
after install tslib( with some warning) and change the /usr/local/tslib permission from root to owner user of pc and run configure the Qt i see this error:

> g++ -o "/opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.3/bin/qmake" project.o property.o main.o makefile.o unixmake2.o unixmake.o mingw_make.o option.o winmakefile.o projectgenerator.o meta.o makefiledeps.o metamakefile.o xmloutput.o pbuilder_pbx.o borland_bmake.o msvc_dsp.o msvc_vcproj.o msvc_nmake.o msvc_objectmodel.o symmake.o initprojectdeploy_symbian.o symmake_abld.o symmake_sbsv2.o registry.o epocroot.o qtextcodec.o qutfcodec.o qstring.o qtextstream.o qiodevice.o qmalloc.o qglobal.o qbytearray.o qbytearraymatcher.o qdatastream.o qbuffer.o qlist.o qfile.o qfsfileengine_unix.o qfsfileengine_iterator_unix.o qfsfileengine.o qfsfileengine_iterator.o qregexp.o qvector.o qbitarray.o qdir.o qdiriterator.o quuid.o qhash.o qfileinfo.o qdatetime.o qstringlist.o qabstractfileengine.o qtemporaryfile.o qmap.o qmetatype.o qsettings.o qlibraryinfo.o qvariant.o qvsnprintf.o qlocale.o qlinkedlist.o qurl.o qnumeric.o qcryptographichash.o qxmlstream.o qxmlutils.o
>   **The tslib functionality test failed!
>   You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing
>   QMAKE_INCDIR and QMAKE_LIBDIR in
>   /opt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.3/mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-g++.**

in one of comment in that site i see : "according to my knowledge this may occur due to two reasons…one is that you may miss typed or dropped some part of the qmake.conf while copying…..else it will be a permission issue". but i copy paste the qmake.conf(and correct the path of compiler to my path) and do the same as the site. but i have this error. some days a go i have the same error. but i solved that with chmod 777 -R /usr/local/tslib and make a program on mini 2440 and it run on my device( but the touch not work) i thought maybe my tslib is wrong and i remove them and install again. but now i have exactly thet error and not solve it.
***I AM SO CONFUSED.PLEASE HELP ME :(***

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], your question is very badly formatted and might be lacking vital information. Note that gcc 4.4.3 is pretty old and might not support your ARM platform properly (at least it lacks major optimizations for that platform, inlcuding LTO).

Comment: i mean i do the same as this site: http://qtinstall.blogspot.in/ but i have this error while ./configure the Qt-4.6.2. my gcc in from in my arm dvd. my arm is too old. i just want to program it. but i have this error The tslib functionality test failed! You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR and QMAKE_LIBDIR in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these error occurred in some conditions like below:

1. before installing your qt-everywhere, you installed tslib( and not successfully install) to solve this you should clean all tslib libs file from your OS
2. if you configure the qt before( call configure again ) to solve this problem you should clean last configure by this way: cd /opt/qt..../qmake -> rm *.o . by this codes you clean last failed configure.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the CXX flag in the bashrc file and run the whole process again.

Comment: i do that but nothing change